# What does the series expansion look like when $\ln(1+x)$ is $x>1$？

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I know that $\ln(1+x)$ can be expanded by Taylor at $x\in(-1,1)$, and the expanded sequence diverges. However, according to the definition, as long as the function is analytic at a certain point and its neighborhood, then it can be expanded at this point, and $\ln(1+x)$ is indeed non-analytic when $x\le -1$ cannot be expanded, but when $x\ge1$, the function is analytic. What does the series expansion expression of this function look like? If it cannot be expanded, why?

Comment: Around what point do you want to expand it in a series?

Comment: If $x>1$, then $\ln(1+x)=\ln x +\ln(1+1/x)=\ln x+\ln(1+y)$, where $y<1$.

Comment: You have to expand it around another point (say, $x_0=1$) and the new radius of convergence will be (for complicated reasons) $R=x_0+1$. The expansion can be calculated with Taylor formula $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$. So in this case it's $\ln(1+x_0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(1+x_0)^k}(x-x_0)^k$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you very much, that is to say, the form of $\ln(1+x)$ expanding $(x_0\ge1)$ at $x_0$ is the same as the form of $x_0\in(-1,1)$, It's just that it probably won't hold back anymore, right?